# Programming a number theory programme

Tags: python, c, math, numbers, wolfram-mathematica

I have this thing that I want to programme which goes as follows.

We all know the next two identities:

> 3<sup>2</sup>+4<sup>2</sup>=5<sup>2</sup>
>   3<sup>3</sup>+4<sup>3</sup>+5<sup>3</sup>=6<sup>3</sup>

Now, I want to write a computer code (in mathematica,C or Python) that will check for such relations.

E.g, for 3<sup>4</sup>+4<sup>4</sup>+5<sup>4</sup>+6<sup>4</sup> compare it with 7<sup>4</sup> and check if it equals to it or not, I mean I want to check for more cases of such a sequence of numbers as above and compare them if indeed they make a sequence as above.

Basically I know I need here a loop and conditionals, my problem is how do I keep the numbers 3,4,5,6,... to keep being generated in the sequences?

This is where I am bugged down as to how to write this code.

I mean I would like to check for upto i=10,000, i.e:
3<sup>i</sup>+4<sup>i</sup>+5<sup>i</sup>+... does it equal (3+i)<sup>i</sup> etc...

I hope you understood my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the $ are for beginning and ending a formula environment in LaTex.

Comment: Have you thought through how long this might take? Back of an envelope order-of-magnitude guess is acceptable.  A sloppy approach for 4 variables is a loop that takes each variable from 1 to 10000.  That is  (10^4)^4 = 10^16 operations.  If the program can do 1,000,000 ops per second, that is 10^10 seconds.  and google tells me "10^10 seconds in years" is 316.8 years.

Comment: Indeed, Codor. I am just registerd at too many stackexchange sites, and in the math and physics they use latex, so the dollar signs come from there. The ^ is power, e.g 3^2 = 3*3; etc.

Comment: You pretty much wrote it already: $\sum_{0<= j <=i} (3+j)^i == (3+i)^i$ -> just replace the sum with a loop and you will have some code to show us.

Comment: @Paul, no I haven't thought how long this might take; I just have an itch to check if there are more cases as the above, just out of curiosity. I am not sure how to write such a code, because I need all the time to increase the sequence and change the exponent.

Comment: @val, you mean upto j<=i-1. Yes, you are right it does seems easy, don't know how I didn't come to this. Thanks.

Comment: There's obviously a better algorithm, but even avoiding duplicates it is still seems like it will be a combinatorially exploding problem as more variables are added.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist glad I could help (and indeed, you are obviously right about indices). Although as Paul mentioned, this naive algorithms will very quickly become unusable if you start iterating over all the different possible exponents.

Comment: What you might do, is decide on an efficient algorithm and run it in parallel on CUDA on one or more computers with a high performance GPU.

Comment: There are libraries in python for this, and also on Mathematica/Matlab I believe.   Though I have not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for pow in xrange(2,5):
    sum=0
    for index in xrange(3,3+pow):
        sum+=index ** pow
    if sum==(index+1) ** pow:
        print True

#output is for power 2, 3 it works
```

i took it for range of 2,5

ie first loop calculates `3**2 + 4 **2 ==5 **2` ..soo on

increase the pow range to 10001 for all 10000 powers

Comment: `index+1 **pow` - does this really do what you wanted it to?

Comment: @Hammerite yes actually take first loop index values are 3,4 and i want to equate it with final value of index=4 +1 ie 5..

Answer (score 1):

> mean I would like to check for upto i=10,000, i.e: 3i+4i+5i+... does it equal (3+i)i etc...

Accounting for the way `range` works, and printing only when `True`:

```
limit = 10000
for pow in range(2, limit + 1):
    if ((3 + pow) ** pow == sum([exp ** pow for exp in range(3, 3 + pow)])):
        print pow
```

Comment: Though yes, it is kind of burning up my resources at the moment ;)

Comment: I ran it yesterday (printing false cases up to 10003) and it just finished a while ago:

real 1460m14.559s
user 1452m28.582s
sys 3m5.596s

Answer (score 1):

This tries to avoid re-doing calculations as much as possible.

```
>>> def f(n):
...    c = 1
...    L1 = [3]
...    L2 = [1]
...    while (c + 3 < n):
...       L2 = [L1[i] * L2[i] for i in range(c)]
...       c += 1
...       x = (c + 2) ** (c - 1)
...       print(c, x == sum(L2))
...       L1.append(c + 2)
...       L2.append(x)
...
>>> f(10)
(2, False)
(3, True)
(4, True)
(5, False)
(6, False)
(7, False)
>>>
```

Comment: To be fair the fastest answer would be `if (pow > 3) print "Don't waste your time."` ;)

Comment: @icedwater, do you have a proof for this claim? (Though my conjecture is that these are indeed the only cases).

Comment: If you compute `(n+3)^n - Sum[ (i+2)^n , {i,1,n} ]` you will see it monotonically blows up for `n>3`. This is proof (or the beginnings of one) that there are no more solutions.

Comment: I have a proof for this claim, but it's too small to fit in this margin... well, seriously, I haven't thought about it, but it's my conjecture too. In fact I was surprised the second case worked.

Comment: @George, I think I can use here the binomial for (n+3)^n and then by induction show that it's greater than the sum of (i+2)^n for n>3. I'll check for this later, after I finish attending my other stuff. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Mathematica it's quite easy:

```
For[i = 3, i < 101, i++ ]
If[Sum[(3 + j)^i, {j, 0, i - 1}] == (3 + i)^i, Print[i]]
```

I am pretty much sure that in other programming languages it may run faster, though.